# Add only a field from another collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have two collections

A with schema

```
{
    a : Array,
    b : ObjectID
}
```

and B with the following schema

```
{
    x : 'string',
    y : // some object schema
    ...
    b : ObjectID
}
```

I want to use mongo aggregate to add a new field in collections B to include only a from collection A searching using b.

I want my value after aggregation to have the following schema :

```
{
    x : 'string',
    newField : a // array from collection A
    y : // some object schema
    ...
    b : ObjectID
}
```

only $lookup does not work because i do not want the whole object and also merge will remove _id and merge others which i do not want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm answering this myself after solving it.

This can be done as a pipeline of operations as follows :

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "A",
        localField: "b",
        foreignField: "b",
        as: "someField"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
      newField  : "$someField.a"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$newField"
},
{
    $project: {
        someField: 0
    }
}
```

---

More efficient answers will be accepted

Comment: I don't see any other way, but according to the optimization documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ $unwind stage should be immediately after $lookup if possible

Comment: @PedroMVU I don't see how they could move $unwind earlier as they only created $newField the stage before

Comment: Nevermind, you could use unwind on somefield and move it up a stage